# MAUI , How to access in a collectionView to a determinate control

Tags: c#, maui, collectionview

I have a CollectionView with some controls in <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>, two of then are ImageButton. I would like to change the source if I have sound or not. The next is my code:

```
<CollectionView  x:Name="lvWords" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" ZIndex="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding WordsGroups}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionChanged="lvWords_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="24"  FontAttributes="Bold"  />
                    <Label Text="W"  TextColor="Black"                BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="14" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"      VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Ipauk}" TextColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Italic"  />
                    <ImageButton x:Name="imgbUk1"       ZIndex="4"                        Margin="5,0,0,0"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="0" Source="uk_sound.png" HeightRequest="48" WidthRequest="48" Clicked="imgbUk_Clicked"/>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="imgbUs1"       ZIndex="5"                        Margin="5,0,0,0"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="0" Source="us_sound.png"  HeightRequest="48" WidthRequest="48" Clicked="imgbUs1_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height = "10"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                        <Label Text="(" TextColor="GreenYellow"               BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="14" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Type}" TextColor="GreenYellow"   BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="14" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text=")"  TextColor="GreenYellow"              BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="14" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"      VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Translation}" TextColor="Wheat" Margin="20,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="14" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="30,0,0,0">
                        <Label Text="("                TextColor="GreenYellow" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Level}"  TextColor="GreenYellow" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Text=")"                TextColor="GreenYellow" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Mainmeaning}"  Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

My idea is to change the IsEnabled property in imgbUk1 and imgbUs1 depending on whether I have sound or not, but my problem is that I don’t know how to access imgbUk1 and imgbUs1 control from my code C#:

```
List<Words> list = new List<Words>();
// First, Group the words to add to the CollectionView
var dict = words.GroupBy(o => o.Word).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
// Get the the words to find the pronuntation's sound into the Data Base.
List<string> _words_list = dict.Keys.ToList();
sounds = await _iWord_SoundsRepository.GetGroupWords_Sound(_words_list);

WordsGroups = new List<WordsGroup>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Words>> item in dict)
{
  WordsGroups.Add(new WordsGroup(item.Key, new List<Words>(item.Value), "  /" + item.Value[0].IPAUK + "/ " + " /" + item.Value[0].IPAUS + "/", new List<Words>(item.Value)));
  // In this point, if the Header word has sound I wnant:
  var sound = sounds.Where(q => q.Word == item.Key.ToString()).Select(x => x.Sound1);
  if (sound==null)
      imgbUks1.IsEnabled= false;
      sound = sounds.Where(q => q.Word == item.Key.ToString()).Select(x => x.Sound2);
  if (sound == null)
       imgbUs1.IsEnabled = false;
}
lvWords.ItemsSource = WordsGroups;
lblStatus.Text = "Fouund Words:" + dict.Count.ToString();
```

In this code, the error I get is:

**The name 'imgbUks1' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: You don’t.  Bind the property to a VM property and update the VM.  Do not try to directly modify the UI from code

Comment: @Jason, How Can I do it?

Comment: Bind the Source to a property in your VM just like you do with your other bindings

Comment: That is a good idea, but if I want to change the enabled property if the word does not have sound?

Comment: Then bind that property to a bool on your VM

Comment: You cannot access the control using x:Name in DataTemplate. Try using data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot access the control in DataTemplate by using **x:Name**. I recommend to use data bindings. GroupHeader also binds to each Words Group. So each Groupheader behaves differently. Make some changes to the **WordsGroup** and binds the IsEnabled property could make it. I  make a small demo.

**Note:** I don't know what the exactly data in your **sounds list**. To make it easy, I suppose it's a list consists of different strings (if has no sound it may return a null string) and each Group has a corresponding value in sound list.

So for **WordsGroup**, just add a new property named it **Sound**. You could also implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**, then UI will change if data source change. For more info, you could refer to [Viewmodels and property-change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode?view=net-maui-7.0#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications)

```
public class WordsGroup : List<Words>,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public string sound { get; set; }
    public string Sound
    {
        get
        {
            return sound;
        }
        set
        {
            sound = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Sound)));
        }
    }

    public Grouped_list(string name, List<Words> words, string sound) : base(words) // You may add other property in your case
    {
        Name = name;
        Sound = sound;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In ViewModel, we make some changes to the construction of **WordsGroups**. We add a new value that is sound, which get from **GetGroupWords_Sound** method.

```
int count = 0  // ensure that each words group and sound is corresponding
foreach (var key in _words_list)
{
    // I notice you have added other property which I don't take into consideration. 
    WordsGroups.Add(new WordsGroup(key, new List<Words>(dict[key]), sounds[count]));
    count ++;
}
```

**Finally**, we could consume it in CollectionView. We have a lot of ways to do it. That depends on the data type in the sounds list. In this example, we suppose sounds list is consist of string (if no sound, it is null). we could use a StringToBoolConverter. For more info, you could refer to [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-7.0).

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="StringToBool"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
......

    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                
    ......
                // in this way, we change string sound to bool based on whether it is null or not
                <ImageButton x:Name="imgbUk1" IsEnabled={Binding Sound,Converter={StaticResource StringToBool}}  />  

            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

For ***StringToBoolConverter.cs***, such like this:

```
public class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public StringToBoolConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "")
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you. If you still have any question, feel free to ask.